# Position text baseline

Tags: inkscape, text, alignment

How do I specify the position of a line of text relative to the baseline,
rather than relative to its lowest point?

I can see the little white square next to the baseline; however,
I am unable to select it or position it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Snap Controls Bar, set the following options

- Enable snapping
- Snap other points (centres, guide origins, gradient handles, etc)
- Snap text anchors and baselines

Then you can snap the text baseline anchor to a guide.

[image]

If you also engage the following options

- Snap nodes paths and handles
- Snap to paths

Then you can snap the text baseline anchor to a path

[image]

Comment: Additionally, the 'Align and Distribute' dialog has a couple of options for aligning text anchors to each other